# Color by manual scale for geom errorbar

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, errorbar

I am having trouble trying to set my errorbars to manual colors to follow the color scheme I have set for my points.  Essentially, I would like the color of each errorbar to match the fill color of it's associated point.

Create dataframe

```
mean<-c(4,5,6,7)
CI<-c(0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2)
stress<-c(1,2,3,4)
a<-c(10,10,20,20)
b<-c(7.5,7.5,8,8)
data<-data.frame(mean,CI,stress,a,b)
```

Original Plot

```
library(ggplot2)
p<- ggplot(data, aes(a, mean))
p+geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=mean+CI,ymin=mean-CI), width=0.3, color=factor(stress))+
  geom_point(aes(fill=factor(stress)),size=8, shape=21)+
  scale_fill_manual("Stress",breaks=c(1,2,3,4),values=c("#0072B2", "#009E73", "#E69F00", "#D55E00"))+
  scale_x_continuous("Level A",breaks=c(10,20))+
  ylab(expression("Level B"))+
  theme_bw(17)
```

Attempt to create manually colored error bars, but didn't work

```
p<- ggplot(data, aes(a, mean))
    p+geom_point()+
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=mean+CI,ymin=mean-CI), width=0.3, color=factor(stress))+
scale_color_manual("Stress", breaks=c(1,2,3,4),values=c("#0072B2", "#009E73", "#E69F00", "#D55E00"))+
      geom_point(aes(fill=factor(stress)),size=8, shape=21)+
      scale_fill_manual("Stress",breaks=c(1,2,3,4),values=c("#0072B2", "#009E73", "#E69F00", "#D55E00"))+
      scale_x_continuous("Level A",breaks=c(10,20))+
      ylab(expression("Level B"))+
      theme_bw(17)

p<- ggplot(data, aes(a, mean))
        p+geom_point()+
          geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=mean+CI,ymin=mean-CI), width=0.3, color=factor(stress))+
    scale_fill_manual("Stress", breaks=c(1,2,3,4),values=c("#0072B2", "#009E73", "#E69F00", "#D55E00"))+
          geom_point(aes(fill=factor(stress)),size=8, shape=21)+
          scale_fill_manual("Stress",breaks=c(1,2,3,4),values=c("#0072B2", "#009E73", "#E69F00", "#D55E00"))+
          scale_x_continuous("Level A",breaks=c(10,20))+
          ylab(expression("Level B"))+
          theme_bw(17)
```

Comment: I modified `geom_errorbar` in your first attempt to manually set the colors to `geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=mean+CI,ymin=mean-CI, color=factor(stress)), width=0.3)`. The handles are colored the same as the fill. Is this what you're after?

Comment: I am trying to get the handles to be the same colors as the fill, yes.  However, I am still not getting the correct colors on the handles.  They are colored, but they do not match the fill of the points.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me.

```
ggplot(data, aes(a, mean)) +
    geom_point()+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=mean+CI,ymin=mean-CI, color=factor(stress)), width=0.3)+
    scale_color_manual("Stress", breaks=c(1,2,3,4),values=c("#0072B2", "#009E73", "#E69F00", "#D55E00"))+
    geom_point(aes(fill=factor(stress)),size=8, shape=21)+
    scale_fill_manual("Stress",breaks=c(1,2,3,4),values=c("#0072B2", "#009E73", "#E69F00", "#D55E00"))+
    scale_x_continuous("Level A",breaks=c(10,20))+
    ylab(expression("Level B"))+
    theme_bw(17)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to remove the outline around the points, or color it the same way?  I am trying to use this solution, but I have a lot more data, and the black border blocks out the color of the points.

Comment: @LinaBird use a different `shape`. Search the internet for the codepage. 21, for example, is a transparent circle with a black border.