# How can I add error bars to a ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data sets like below

```
df1<- structure(list(time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("24", "48", "72"), class = "factor"), place = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("B,C", "D,E", "F,G"
), class = "factor"), key = c("boy1", "boy2", "boy3", "boy1", 
"boy2", "boy3", "boy1", "boy2", "boy3"), value = c(177.72258835, 
0, 74.438539625, 134.3410045, 48915.1, 38.302204425, 97.32286187, 
25865.25, 28.67291878), x = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", 
"2", "3"), y = c(177.72258835, 0, 74.438539625, 134.3410045, 
48915.1, 38.302204425, 97.32286187, 25865.25, 28.67291878)), .Names = c("time", 
"place", "key", "value", "x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")


df2<- structure(list(time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("24", "48", "72"), class = "factor"), place = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("B,C", "D,E", "F,G"
), class = "factor"), key = c("boy1", "boy2", "boy3", "boy1", 
"boy2", "boy3", "boy1", "boy2", "boy3"), value = c(58.852340736, 
0, 21.291893740908, 42.92051958201, 72521.52726, 16.309811239722, 
32.403556124268, 38347.81965, 10.342042262244), x = c("1", "2", 
"3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"), y = c(58.852340736, 0, 21.291893740908, 
42.92051958201, 72521.52726, 16.309811239722, 32.403556124268, 
38347.81965, 10.342042262244)), .Names = c("time", "place", "key", 
"value", "x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to plot them together with `df2` as the standard deviation for `df1`

when I plot `df1`, I do the following

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y, col = key)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("first", "second", "third"), limits = c(1, 2,3)) +
   facet_grid(time ~ .)
```

but now I want to have the second df as the standard deviation (i.e., the first y-value in `df1` is 177.72259, so it's standard deviation is the corresponding y-value in `df2`, which is 58.85234).

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `geom_errorbar`? See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082149/color-by-manual-scale-for-geom-errorbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you want to include error bars in your plot. This can be accomplished using only a single data frame, if you just add the standard error as an additional variable like so:

```
df <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
      .Label = c("24", "48", "72"), class = "factor"), place = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
      2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("B,C", "D,E", "F,G"), class = "factor"), 
      key = c("boy1", "boy2", "boy3", "boy1", "boy2", "boy3", "boy1", "boy2", "boy3"), 
      value = c(58.852340736, 0, 21.291893740908, 42.92051958201, 72521.52726,
      16.309811239722, 32.403556124268, 38347.81965, 10.342042262244), 
      x = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"), y = c(177.72258835, 0, 
      74.438539625, 134.3410045, 48915.1, 38.302204425, 97.32286187, 25865.25, 28.67291878), 
      sd = c(58.852340736, 0, 21.291893740908, 42.92051958201, 72521.52726, 16.309811239722, 
      32.403556124268,38347.81965, 10.342042262244)), .Names = c("time", "place", "key", 
      "value", "x", "y", "sd"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then you can add error bars to the plot using `geom_errorbar()`, as follows (I am borrowing the "free-y" scale trick from @jazzurro's answer above):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col = key)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("first", "second", "third"), limits = c(1, 2,3)) +
  facet_grid(time ~ .) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y-sd, ymax = y+sd)) +
  facet_grid(time ~ ., scale = "free_y")
```

[image]

Unfortunately your data is a little skewed, in that some measurements are way larger in magnitude than others (especially at time=48 and time=72); you may want to consider a log transformation so that the error bars for the smaller observations do not appear so negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way for you. I changed the shape of the sd in the second `geom_point()`. Since the y-scale has a wide range for two of the plots, you see points overlapping.

```
ggplot() +
geom_point(data = df1, aes(x, y, col = key)) +
geom_point(data = df2, aes(x, y, col = key), shape = 22, alpha = 0.3) +
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("first", "second", "third"), limits = c(1, 2, 3)) +
facet_grid(time ~ ., scale = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: I am off to work now. So I cannot get back to you for a while. If any revision is necessary, I am happy to work with you later. Hope you do not mind that.

Comment: thanks for the message, it would be nice to have the sd as + and - and have a line across each set (like boy1 has a line from first, second and third)

Comment: @NikBernou How do you wanna use + and -? Which values have + and which values have -?

Comment: @NikBernou it seems that you needed error bars. I wish you could state that from the beginning. Anyway, you got a good answer now. Good luck.